# How to execute dart code from Android service in background

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am actually trying to make an app that gets your position when you move and send it to my server. All the point of my application is that it should send the position even if the app is closed.

My app is running with Flutter but I have a little problem.

I made an Android service that runs in background and looks for position updates. And that is working great.
But I want my service to run a dart function to send the data to my server with socket IO or HTTP request(maybe HTTP is better).
So how can I make my service call a dart function that runs even when the app is closed?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did you try this package? I have used it for what you mention. https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Comment: I have not tried that package because it says that it works only every 15 minutes. I need it to work in realtime. I want to be able to locate somebody in realtime. But maybe this is something not possible when the app is killed.